# How to change a color of a syntax in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: syntax, colors, visual-studio-code, token

For example, if I am writing latex in VS Code, I've selected a theme, but want to fine tweak it.

If I want to change the coloring of a citation item, for example, the letters `abc98` in `\cite{abc98}`, what should I do?

In Atom, you can open up the devtools, and select the item, and see the css scope. Can't do that in VS Code; it shows something like `mk21`, which doesn't make sense.

[This page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes) contain very little information. If the syntax I want to change is not within the mentioned "comments", "variables" etc. I don't know how to find the correct token (is that the word?)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can one tune the colors in User Settings at all? Or do I have to write my own theme to do this?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_textmate-theme-rules

Comment: You can, only if the grammar for a file defines needed scopes.

Comment: For latex it's probably `keyword.control.cite`, `constant.other.reference.citation`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Took me a while to figure out how to put things together in user settings.

Answer (score 15):

From the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes):

> To tune the editor's syntax highlighting colors, use editor.tokenColorCustomizations in your user settings settings.json file

Besides simple token customization you can fully override the TextMate rules with a slightly more complex setting, for example:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {"textMateRules": [{
        "scope": "keyword.control.ref.latex",
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#FF0000"
        }
    }]}
```

Comment: How do you examine the scope of a given selection in a document?

Comment: @IsaacLubow With the cursor on top of the word, access the Command Pallete (`Ctrl+Shift+P`), search for `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` and hit enter.

Comment: You have to use the auto-suggest keyboard shortcut  (also called "trigger suggest") to show the available syntax colors to customize. As of April 2023, only 7 things can be customized: "comments", "functions", "strings", "numbers", "keywords", "types", "variables".